# Custom authorization parameter for a policy

Tags: php, authorization, laravel-5.4

Usually, with a policy, you only have the parameters `user` and a corresponding model. It does not seem to work to have custom parameters attached, though.

What I would like:

```
// MyModelPolicy.php
class MyModelPolicy
{
     public function foo(User $user, MyModel $model, $someString) { /* ... */ }
}
```

And then in Blade:

```
// some.blade.php
@can('foo', $myModelInstance, 'tralala')
```

However, I get the error that `foo` expects exactly three parameters and is only getting two. Laravel Gate only delivers two and ignores `'tralala'`.

What is the easiest way to accomplish what I desire?

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out that this is easier than thought of... The documentation fails to give a short example on this but all you have to do is, use `@can` in a distinct way:

```
// some.blade.php
@can('foo', [$myModelInstance, 'tralala'])
```

Well, if you look up the API reference, you will see that `can` wants an array and the rest follows.